# SQL Temp table life time during multiple stored procedure calls

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure with 2 different behaviors. First case it does things and create a local temp table (`#MyTempTable`). Second case check the existence of the temp table and if it exists then works on it. BUT at the second call the temp table doesn't exist anymore. As I know it shouldn't be deleted until the connection is alive.

Why?

Currently I solved it with global temp table(`##MyTempTable`) but I would like to know why the server deletes the file.

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using.

Comment: If SQL Server a local temp table created in a procedure is dropped when that procedure returns.

Comment: Thank you @Alex K.So it's a fact, let's face it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the second stored procedure from your first stored procedure. If you create a `temp` table in one stored procedure then after the flow exits this SP, the `temp` table is dropped. Do something like below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Procedure1
AS 
    [parameters]
BEGIN
   EXEC Procedure2 [parameters];
END
```

In this way, your second SP will have access to local  `temp`  table created in first SP.

Comment: Thank you Sanket D. Unfortunately it's not convenient for me because the SP is being called from the application multiple times because it moves large amount of data from the server. So basically the second part of the SP loops on the records of the temp table based on the Start and End rowindex which are it's input parameters.